# Search for string using VBscript and copy that column to another worksheet

Tags: vbscript

I have Book1.csv and Book2.xlsx. Book1.csv has many columns with data. Each column has unique title in first ROW. I need to find column with title “Processor Time” and copy all available data in this column to column1 in Book2.xlsx using VBscript. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADO to get the column:

```
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Docs\;"
strcon = strcon & "Extended Properties=""Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

cn.Open strcon

strSQL = "Select [Processor Time] From [Book1.csv]"

rs.Open strSQL, cn

MsgBox rs.GetString
```

You can use automation with Excel:

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

You can write to Excel from a recordset with:

```
xl.Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
```

You can post back if you have problems putting the bits together.

EDIT re Comment

Try switching your code around a little:

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
xl.Visible = True 
Set objWorkbook1=xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Docs\book2.xlsx") 

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 

strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Docs\;" 
strcon = strcon & "Extended Properties=""Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";" 

cn.Open strcon 
strSQL = "Select [Processor Time] From [Book1.csv]" 
rs.Open strSQL, cn 

objWorkbook1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
```

Comment: I am sorry but I do not know how to put these bits together. My files are located in c:\temp. Please help.

Comment: I get MsgBox with data which is under Processor Time title. I am not sure how to copy this data to  Book2.xlsx column A.

Comment: This opens book2.xlsx but it's empty. It did not copy column data.

Comment: Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 
strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Docs\;" 
strcon = strcon & "Extended Properties=""Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";" 
 
cn.Open strcon 
 
strSQL = "Select [Processor Time] From [Book1.csv]" 
 
rs.Open strSQL, cn 
 
MsgBox rs.GetString 


Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
xl.Visible = True
Set objWorkbook1= xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Docs\book2.xlsx")
objWorkbook1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

Comment: I think it is to do with timing. I have added a note.

Comment: OK. So I have it working. In this script, we only search for "Processor Time" and copied that column. How do I search for more that one strings and copy all those columns. For example, I want to search for tiles "Processor time", "Memory" and "Page Faults" and copy all these columns and paste in book2.xlsx column A, B and C.

Comment: You can list the columns you want: `Select [Processor Time], [Memory], [Page Faults] From [Book1.csv]` You can select all : `Select * From [Book1.csv]` , though it is generally better to list the column names. You can even use WHERE statements : `Select [Processor Time], [Memory], [Page Faults] From [Book1.csv] Where [Page Faults] > 6`

Comment: Thanks. Now, I have a title name "(PDH-CSV 4.0) (Eastern Daylight Time)(240)". When I replace "Processor Time" in above code with new title I get an error "Invalid bracketing of name "(PDH-CSV 4.0) (Eastern Daylight Time)(240)". If there anyway to fix this?

Comment: I can think of three possibilities. 1. Set HDR=No and use F1,F2, F3, ...,Fn for column names. 2. Open the file using the FileSystemObject and change the headers. 3. Use Excel automation for the Book1.csv. Options 1 and 3 are probably the best bet.